# Downloadable map data usable in applications

Tags: format, charts, navigation

I wish to create a small pathfinder application with maps.

Where can I download navigation European map data and find documentation about their formats?

Comment: I have heavily edited your question, please undo the changes if I have altered your intended meaning too much.

Answer (score 1):

> [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) is a free editable map of the whole world. It is made by people like you. OpenStreetMap allows you to view, edit and use geographical data in a collaborative way from anywhere on Earth.

You can export data as XML or as SVG, Postscript etc. The site has a [description](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Data_Primitives) of the XML format.

---

Also note that [Google maps](http://maps.google.com) has an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) which can be used to display your own paths projected onto a Google map.